# Multithreaded game server using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, server

I am quite new at this and would like some help with configuring a C# server for a LAN game. The server needs to send an object to all the clients connected to the server and then wait for their response . After all players respond , the server announces the winner to all participants and generates a new game (After the winner is announced I wait about 5 seconds for the next game to generate)

I'm having trouble sending that object through NetworkStream

Server side:

```
public static void broadcast(string uName, bool flag)
    {
        game.Generate();
        foreach (Client Item in clientsList)
        {
            TcpClient broadcastSocket;
            broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.clientSocket;
            NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
            Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

            if (flag == true)
            {
                broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Winner is " + uName);
            }
            else
            {

                broadcastBytes = ToByteArray(game);

            }

            broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
            broadcastStream.Flush();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ToByteArray(Game24 obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Client side:

```
private void getMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
            try
            {
                GenerateGame(inStream);
                isGame = true;   // testing
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("No object");
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
            }

            if (isGame)
                MessageBox.Show("Works  " + readData);

        }
    }

    private Game24 deserializeData(byte[] arr) {

        IFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
        {
            object obj = br.Deserialize(ms);
            return (Game24)obj;
        }
    }

    private void GenerateGame(byte[] arrBytes)
    {

        game = deserializeData(arrBytes);
        Generate();

            MessageBox.Show("Test2");
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Start();

    }
```

It always shows the "No object" message

Comment: `inStream`'s length is 10025, but `buffSize` 65536. (See `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);`) Getting an exception wouldn't be surprise.

Comment: @L.B can you please be more specific . I have not set anything to 65536 . Is there something that I'm not getting ? Thank you

Comment: `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` is 65536 which bigger than your *inStream*'s length

Comment: _"It always shows the "No object" message"_ -- then an exception was thrown. What was the exception? What's the exact message? Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not practical to try to answer this question. But you clearly haven't spent any time studying how TCP works, because your code makes assumptions it shouldn't make, the biggest one being that when you call `Read()`, you'll get exactly one message that was sent from the remote endpoint. That's just not how TCP works; you can receive any number of bytes...all you can assume is they're in the right order.

Comment: @PeterDuniho this is the first time I try to code an app that requires internet. If it is not too much of a burden to you , can you provide some links to useful stuff for web programming . The code you see it is a modified code of a chat service I found on the internet . I just modified it to work for transferring objects (my knowledge is very poor on web programming ) Thank you

Comment: There are lots of resources available. IMHO, one of the most comprehensive is the [Winsock Programmer’s FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). It's written specifically for the Winsock API, but it covers a lot of other general network topics any person writing network code needs to know, and even the Winsock stuff is still fairly useful, because all of the other APIs, including the .NET network I/O APIs, are built on top of Winsock.